# How to send a personalised email to multiple recipients depending on a condition?

Tags: python

I am making a program which imports an excel file with multiple vehicle registrations and the emails of people the vehicles belong to. The program searches the MOT database using the MOT API and extracts the days left on each vehicle's MOT. I have set a condition where if the days left are less than 30 the program will send an email to the person as reminder. At the moment, my program sends a generic email to everyone on the list whose MOT runs out in 30 days. I would like to personalise the email similar to this example:
"The MOT for your vehicle with registration _______ expires in __ days!"

So the program would take the registration and the days left from my dataframe and send it to the corresponding individual. I assume this will require some sort of a for loop but I am not sure how to implement it. Any help is much appreciated. Here is my code:

```
apiKey = 'abcdxyz'

import requests
from datetime import datetime
import smtplib
import time
import pandas as pd
import pprint as pp
import xlrd

df = pd.read_excel(r'vehicles.xlsx')  # Reading the excel file with the vehicle database
registrations = df['registration'].tolist()  # Converting the registrations column to a list
mobile = df['mobile'].tolist()  # Converting the mobile numbers column to a list
email = df['email'].tolist()  # Converting the email column to a list
list_days_left = []  # Empty list to store data later


# Function to extract days left on MOT using the given dataframe:
def check_days_left(regi):
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'x-api-key': apiKey,
    }
    params = (
        ('registration', regi),
    )
    response = requests.get('https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/trade/vehicles/mot-tests',
                            headers=headers, params=params)
    r = response.json()  # This returns a list of dicts of the full MOT History data
    carDetails = r[0]  # Access the first dictionary of the list
    motTests = carDetails['motTests']  # This returns a list of dicts again of the MOT tests
    latestTest = motTests[0]  # Access the first dictionary to get the details of the latest test
    expDate = latestTest['expiryDate']  # This returns the expiry date key of the latest test dictionary
    uk_date = datetime.strptime(expDate, '%Y.%m.%d')  # Convert expDate to datetime format
    difference = uk_date - datetime.now()  # Gets the timedelta between now and expiry date
    days_left = difference.days  # Extract the number of days from the above as an int
    return days_left


# Function to apply the above function to each registration in the dataframe and append it to the empty list creater earlier:
def get_days_left():
    for reg in registrations:
        list_days_left.append(check_days_left(reg))
    # print(list_days_left)

    df['days_left'] = list_days_left
    # print(df)

    df.drop(df[df.days_left > 30].index, axis=0, inplace=True)
    print(df)
    return df


# Function to send emails:
def send_mail(m):
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()

    server.login('myemail@gmail.com', 'mypassword')
    subject = 'Your MOT is expiring soon!'
    body = f"The MOT for your vehicle is running out soon!"
    msg = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'

    server.sendmail(
        'myemail@gmail.com',
        m,
        msg
    )
    print('EMAIL HAS BEEN SENT!')

    server.quit()


# Calling the function to return a dataframe with just those vehicles whose MOT runs out in 30 days:
get_days_left()


# Calling the function to send email to each person on the list:
for mailid in df['email']:
    send_mail(mailid)
```

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.  Best of all, each tutorial will teach you a collection of related techniques, rather than merely solving the immediate problem.  "some sort of for loop" suggests that you should work through a tutorial or two on iteration and filtering of data base rows.  Try a PANDAS data frame for your data?

Answer (score 1):

In the `get_days_left` method, in the for loop you could get the days left from the `check_days_left` function and do a check there. As for the infomation such as their registration, you already have it because you're passing the registration to the `check_days_left` method.

```py
def get_days_left():
    for reg in registrations:
        days_left = check_days_left(reg)
        # Assuming days_left is an integer
        if days_left < 30:
            send_mail("ownersemail@email.com", reg=reg, days_left=days_left)

def send_mail(ownerEmail, reg, days_left):
    # Send the mail here.
    server.sendmail("me@mymail.com", ownerEmail, f"Your vehicle with registration: {reg} has {days_left} days left!")
```

I apologise for any formatting errors or if my response isn't top-notch, I haven't posted here before.
Edit: Added how `send_mail` could look for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

```
for vehicle in r:
 # do work
```

Inside the loop you'll access all the variables and send the mail.